# how to drag and save outlook email into WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, outlook

I am creating a WPF application. i want to drag email from outlook into this wpf application and application needs to save it in a specific folder. i have tried using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C article. It works fine for winform. i tried using same code in WPF after fixing all compile time bugs but still it is not working.

I have searched web a lot but cannot find any working solution for this problem. Can someone please provide any working sample code?

Comment: outloock what version you have?

Comment: i am using outlook 2013

Comment: Strange ... I'm running analysis of the letter. Try to analyze your EmailObject code below.

Comment: while accessing data for format 'FileContent'. I am getting this error 'Invalid lindex (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040068 (DV_E_LINDEX))'

Comment: while accessing data for format 'FileName' and 'FileNameW', i am getting this error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

!!! Add references: "**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll**" !!!
(Search in your disks)

Analyzee your DragObject:

WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        x:Name="thisForm"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Drop="ContainerDrop" DragOver="ContainerDragOver" Name="f_DropText" AllowDrop="True"/>
</Window>
```

c#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void ContainerDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
      f_DropText.Text = "";
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (string format in e.Data.GetFormats())
      {
        sb.AppendLine("Format:" + format);
        try
        {
          object data = e.Data.GetData(format);
          sb.AppendLine("Type:" + (data == null ? "[null]" : data.GetType().ToString()));
          if (format == "FileGroupDescriptor")
          {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application OL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            sb.AppendLine("##################################################");
            for (int i = 1; i <= OL.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count; i++)
            {
              Object temp = OL.ActiveExplorer().Selection[i];
              if (temp is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)
              {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailitem = (temp as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem);
                int n=1;
                sb.AppendLine("Mail " + i + ": " + mailitem.Subject);
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment attach in mailitem.Attachments)
                {
                  sb.AppendLine("File " + i + "."+n+": " + attach.FileName);
                  sb.AppendLine("Size " + i + "."+n+": " + attach.Size);
                  sb.AppendLine("For save using attach.SaveAsFile");
                  ++n;
                }
              }
            }
            sb.AppendLine("##################################################");
          }
          else
            sb.AppendLine("Data:" + data.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          sb.AppendLine("!!CRASH!! " + ex.Message);
        }
        sb.AppendLine("=====================================================");
      }
      f_DropText.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
    private void ContainerDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
      e.Handled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: while accessing data for format 'FileContent'. I am getting this error 'Invalid lindex (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040068 (DV_E_LINDEX))'

Comment: while accessing data for format 'FileName' and 'FileNameW', i am getting this error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Repeat again with OutLook interlop object!

Comment: how can i convert IDataObject intoOuLook Interop object

Comment: If content `FileGroupDescriptor` in `e.Data.GetFormats()` then I create `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application` and get all `ActiveExplorer().Selection`, next i check any `Selection`. If is `MailItem` then get all property mail. Other options I can not see. Copy all code in new project and check drag object again.

Comment: For WPF - see my answer below. This works without any Office Interop assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I got this working.

I took this guys code at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/outlook_drag_drop_in_cs.aspx and altered it to work with WPF.

But it was not easy since there were few constructs that had changed in the underlying COM constructs of System.Windows, so it did not work just by changing from system.windows to s.w.forms.IDataObject.

Then I found this github code from this thread
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5853bfc1-61ac-4c20-b36c-7ac500e4e2ed/how-to-drag-and-drop-email-msg-from-outlook-to-wpfor-activex-for-upload-and-send-them-out-via?forum=wpf

http://gist.github.com/521547  - *This is the new IDataObject that works with WPF*.

Has corrections to accomodate System.Windows.IDataObject instead of S.W.Forms.IDataObject and '_innerData' should be used to query for data, along with fixes for some memory access issues. The guy has nailed it !

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to recover the dropped mail item object you need to detect that something was fropped from Outlook and then connect to the running Outlook instance using the [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject.aspx) method which obtains a running instance of the specified object from the running object table (ROT).

Then you can get the Selection object using the [Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861267(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Explorer class. It returns a Selection object that contains the item or items that are selected in the explorer window.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void lbAttachments_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) || e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor") ? DragDropEffects.All : DragDropEffects.None;
        }

        private void lbAttachments_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor"))
            {
                try {
                    var dataObject = new OutlookDataObject(e.Data);
                    var filePaths = new StringCollection();

                    string[] fileContentNames = (string[])dataObject.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor");
                    if (fileContentNames.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        var fileStreams = (MemoryStream[])dataObject.GetData("FileContents");

                        for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < fileContentNames.Length; fileIndex++)
                        {
                            var ms = fileStreams[fileIndex];
                            var bytes = ms.ToArray();

                            AddAttachment(fileContentNames[fileIndex], bytes);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception) { /* ignore */ }

            }
            else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                string[] s = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
                if (s == null)
                    return;

                foreach (string file in s)
                    AddAttachment(file);
            }
private void AddAttachment(string argFilename)
        {
            var daten = File.ReadAllBytes(argFilename);
            AddAttachment(argFilename, daten);
        }
```