# Is there any possible way to drag entire email information (.msg) from outlook and drop into web application?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, drag-and-drop

My web application want to move out from third party add-on for drag and drop email from outlook. Currently looking for way to do it and just want to make sure i'm on the correct track.

I had tried and test the sample in drag and drop in winForm (
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C but it ) and WPF Application ( [how to drag and save outlook email into WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405596/how-to-drag-and-save-outlook-email-into-wpf-application) ) but both does not work in web application after the changes i made.

The email does not load into my web application and no error shown on the web page.

Noted : The third party software is an add-on on IE and only work on IE. That why i wanted to move out from it.

Comment: Hi ZenZhiin, welcome to stackoverflow. did you know the reason that the example you found is specifically for windows application, not a website one? this is due to the fact how [drag and drop works is similar to copy-paste in general](https://superuser.com/a/1428652/534347). it requires you to interact with the OS directly. and thats perhaps why you need to have a third party add-on on your web browser. i have no idea if HTML5 supports arbitrary OLE drag-and-drop.

Comment: or you could dig [HTML5 drag-and-drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop), it seems to allow arbitrary drop (that [FileSystemEntry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem)). but do remember, that feature is totally experimental, and some browser didnt support it. do a double check on the compatibility list.

Comment: Hi Bagus Tesa, 
yeah i notice the example is specifically for window application that why i tried use it as reference and code it into web application. Noted i will do some research on whether HTML5 supports arbitrary OLE drag-and-drop.

Thank i will do more research on the compatibility list.